# Disable 301 Moved Permanently On wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have two custom templates saved in my templates folder. 
One's called xxxx.php and another is xxxx-test.php.

They are the exact same files except one points to a live API and the other a test API.
In my xxxx.php file I have something like this:

```
if(empty($current_user->user_email)){
    header("Location:/wp-login.php");die;
}
```

I dont have this in the xxxx-test.php.
I want to be able to access xxxx.php only when logged in hence why im checking for the email. For the xxxx-test.php I'd like to give full access.

My problem is that everytime i try to go to the xxxx.php page i get redirected to xxxx-test.php

Anyone know how to stop wordpress from doing this?

Comment: Are they specialized page templates? In other words, do they only work for a single page that has been created in the admin (for example, `page-ID.php`, or `page-slug.php`)

Comment: yes, each one has a different template name and is assigned to one page only.